# Gradle - Android Studio - Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle

При подключении к проекту Firebase Remote Config ошибка:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.0.

Самые последние библиотеки:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Мой Gradle Script:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Вам надо добавить плагин гугла в `build.gradle` уровня проекта, сразу после `android-gradle-plugin` - `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'`

Comment: Покажите скрипт целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Версия `firebase` и пакетов из `play-services` должна быть одинаковая. А у вас firebase `16.0.0`, а тот же `play-services-ads` версии `15.0.1`.

Используйте везде `16.0.0`.

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.gms:google-services:16.0.0

Comment: @RomanShubenko насколько я знаю, сейчас все пакеты нужно отдельно подключать, а не целиком https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Т.е. `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'`. А вместо `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0` подставьте только нужные пакеты.

Comment: Я удалил `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0` и оставил только `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'` - всё равно ошибка

Comment: @RomanShubenko полную синхронизацию градла делали после изменений?

Answer (score 0):

"Русским" языком же написано что надо сделать:

Обновить плагин google-services до последней версии

или

Выставить либу 'com.google.gms:google-services` до версии 16.0.0

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.gms:google-services:16.0.0